# Removing Actors does not delet all Actors

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am currently trying to save special `Actors` so i can put them on a map again if the old map get loaded. Therefor i want to put them into a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Monster>> monsterAtMap` and remove them from there `Stages`. So i am trying this:

```
private void saveMonsters() {
    if (this.screen.figureStage.getActors().size == 0)
        return;
    ArrayList<Monster> monsters = new ArrayList<Monster>();
    for (Actor a : this.screen.figureStage.getActors()) {
        a.remove();
    }
    Gdx.app.log("Figurstage size", ""+ this.screen.figureStage.getActors().size);
    this.monsterAtMap.put(this.currentMap.name, monsters);
}
```

As start. But i noticed that it does not delete all. It does just delete 10 thats all. I do log the `size` of it befor and after the deleting. It's current 21 (20Monsters and 1 Character) after delete the `size` is 11.I also added this `this.screen.figureStage.getRoot().removeActor(a);` but this does not change anything.

Any Idea to that?

[EDIT] I wrote a workaround so my idea is working but the general idea that should work isnt possible because the `.remove()` does not always delete the `Actor` in anyway?! The workaround does look like this:

```
private void saveMonsters() {
    this.chara = this.screen.character;
    if (this.screen.figureStage.getActors().size == 0)
        return;

    ArrayList<Monster> monsters = new ArrayList<Monster>();
    for (Actor a : this.screen.figureStage.getActors()) {
        if (a.getClass() == Monster.class)
            monsters.add((Monster) a);
    }
    this.screen.figureStage.clear();
    this.screen.figureStage.addActor(chara);
    this.monsterAtMap.put(this.currentMap.name, monsters);
}
```

The `.clear()`does work correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting objects from a container while iterating over that container is always fraught with issues and complications, and I think you're running into some of these issues with the `Stage`'s list of actors.  The `Stage` code tries to use `SnapshotArray` to hide some of these issues, but its not clear to me that it will work with the code you've written.

One way to avoid this would be to loop through `getActors()` once and copy the actors into the `monsters` array, then loop through the monsters array and remove the actors from the Stage (or invoke `figureStage.getRoot().clearChildren()`).  This should prevent you from iterating over a list that you're modifying.

Alternatively, look at how [`Group.clearChildren()` is implemented](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Group.java#L271) (it uses an explicit integer index in the array of children, and not an iterator over the Array, and avoid some of the issues).

Comment: yea right this is the correct answer. I did fix that by saving my character and using the clear method. To avoid the nullpointer on mapchange i override the act method to an empty and call the myAct of it infront of the regular Act of the Stage. So if he triggers a mapchange the monster wont act and wont get into these problems.